# Are the flags listed in the new 10k Flags tab listed in the same order as the regular Mod queue?

Tags: support, flags, 10k-tools

10k users can now see the mod flag queue (or at least some of it).

I was wondering if the flags were being presented in the same order that the diamond mods would also see those flags.

Answer (score 6):

It is not in the same order. In fact, it's a completely randomized order from the looks of it, for 10k users. If you refresh the page, it may change the positioning (took a few tries on here, which only has 2 flags so it's only a 50% chance of change).

I also compared it on Gaming against the mod listing, it does indeed appear to be independent.

Answer (score 2):

We explicitly randomize the order of the flags in `tools/flagged`. The moderator only queue is ordered by a - KFC like - secret spice, which ensures the most **important** ones are at the top.

For `tools/flagged` we wanted to get the largest amount of coverage, so we randomize. That also limits the lynching of the horrible posts a tiny bit.

Comment: It would be nice to be able to sort them chronologically too.  Lots of times I will check the flag tab and help with the one I feel are valid, but leave the rest alone.  It would be nice to not have to sift through ones I've already visited if I go back to /flags looking for newer flags.